# Zoom is smoother on maps.google.com than on Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have noticed that the zoom on [maps.google.com](https://maps.google.com) behaves differently (read: smoother) than my custom map using version 3 of the google maps api. I later found out that this also applies to the demo from Google [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

Is there a way to get the same smooth zoom feeling on maps using the Google Maps API v3?

I've been trying to search around the net for a solution, but all I can find is people asking how to do zoom animations, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Google Maps doesn't use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 (at least last I knew).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The native Google Maps site [*maps.google.com*](http://maps.google.com) uses the HTML5 canvas element for rendering maps. The Google Maps API v3 does not**. It is currently (as of late 2015) not possible to get the smooth continuous zoom behavior using the Google Maps API.

After searching Google docs and the web for answers without results, I took some time to understand how the *API v3* and how *maps.google.com* basically work to render and display maps. There's one major difference that makes immediately clear why a continuous zoom won't work using the API:

1. **Google Maps API v3** creates a map made of *image tiles* each rendered into single `<div />` containers with a fixed default size of `256 x 256 px`. When switching the zoom level every single tile has to be re-rendered with a new image (of whatever type, possibly dynamically styled with custom overlays and so on). This is a very expensive task, so every additional zoom step adds extra resources to be loaded and extra computation costs for re-rendering the whole scene via DOM manipulation. A fluid zoom experience is nearly impossible, even with modern browsers on high CPU/memory machines.
2. **maps.google.com** uses the HTML5 *canvas object* for rendering map scenes (I'm pretty sure there's a API v3 style fallback variant for old browsers). Drawing in a natively supported canvas object is way less expensive than replacing images in DOM elements. Google uses a *vector graphics* based approach which basically allows to do a continuous zoom into detail without the need to fetch additional resources. Additionally needed information for a specific zoom level though could be fetched as smaller chunks of data and applied to the drawing routines.

I must admit that I don't know how this works in detail. It's just what I discovered by inspecting the source and I hope it pretty much sums up why a "smooth zoom" is *currently* not possible using the maps API. Anyway, let's look forward to the Google Maps API *v4*!

Answer (score 2):

There are other JavaScript mapping libraries that allow for smooth zooming, such as Mapbox-GL and Cesium.  They both use WebGL, just like maps.google.com.

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/

https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Camera.html&label=Showcases

Answer (score 0):

I think it now depends on whether Google Maps is in [Lite Mode](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966), which seems to be their name for the old-school, image tile-based maps, as opposed to the canvas-based maps.

According to Google Maps' documentation for [System and Browser requirements](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3096703), Maps will disable 3D for certain video cards, and for some video cards, it goes beyond that and only lets you use Lite Mode.